# chromium embedded detect button press

Tags: c++, user-interface, chromium-embedded

I want to use Chromium Embedded Framework as GUI of my OpenGL application.

I am using Off-screen Rendering.

How to detect when a HTML button/link is clicked on?

I tried to google this but with so generic search term there is only noise.
The General Usage wiki also doesn't contain this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should catch an event in JS code and send a message to C++ code. It can be done using a message router described here:
https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage#markdown-header-asynchronous-javascript-bindings

It is also possible to implement a custom message router using JS integration mechanic:
https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/JavaScriptIntegration.md

Answer (score 1):

Do you pass any UI events to CEF from your OpenGL application?

In general you shall attach OpenGL *and* CEF instances to the same window. You shall also override request to invalidate window's area to notify your OpenGL code that it needs to rerender window including content of that on-screen buffer.

Sequence of actions:

1. Window receives mouse move event.
2. Window passes it to your CEF instance.
3. If CEF determines that it needs to apply :hover state to your button then it will call window.invalidateArea(areaOfTheButton).
4. You handle that window.invalidateArea() by updating OpenGL scene including new version of your off-screen bitmap.
5. From CEF you should also receive various secondary DOM events in response to mouse move/up/down/etc. on window.

And check this: http://sciter.com/sciter-and-directx/ - it is DirectX window with integrated HTML/CSS UI with my Sciter Engine. At the moment I am designing the same but for OpenGL.

Comment: I have no problem using CEF as a browser. I just cant catch the button press back in c++ code. I am looking for callbacks/events. I don't know where to look at all.

Comment: It seems that CEF does not provide simple option to subscribe to DOM events. So you will need to register your own native function in it and attach it to the the DOM document object using document.addEventListener(yourfunc)  in script. You will need to use ExecuteJavaScript function to run your setup scripts. .See:
https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/JavaScriptIntegration#markdown-header-using-js-callbacks